# How to factorize this expression?

Tags: calculus

I know that :
$$-2\sin ^{ 2 }{ x } -\quad \sin { x } +\quad 1\quad =\quad -(\sin(x)+1)\quad \times \quad (2\times \sin(x)-1)$$
Is true, but I am not getting at all how to factorise the LHS expression.

Comment: How would you factorize $-2y^2-y+1=-(2y^2+y-1)$? Seems like it is just $-(y+1)(2y-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $\sin x$ by a single term $t$. Then $-2 \sin^2 x - \sin x + 1 = -2t^2 - t + 1 = (-t-1)(2t - 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in this way:

Let $t=\sin x$, then $-2 \sin^2 x-\sin x+1=-2t^2-t+1 =-(2t^2+t-1)=-(2t^2-2-(t+1))

=-(2(t-1)(t+1)-(t+1))=-((2t-1)(t+1)$.

May it is also useful for you.